# Moving large amounts of files from one large folder to several smaller folders using R

Tags: r, file

I have over 7,000 .wav files in one folder which need to be split up into groups of 12 and placed into separate smaller folders.

The files correspond to 1-minute recordings taken every 5 minutes, so every 12 files corresponds to 1 hour.

The files are stored on my PC in the working directory: "E:/Audiomoth Files/Winter/Rural/Emma/"

Examples of the file names are as follows:

```
20210111_000000.wav
20210111_000500.wav
20210111_001000.wav
20210111_001500.wav
20210111_002000.wav
20210111_002500.wav
20210111_003000.wav
20210111_003500.wav
20210111_004000.wav
20210111_004500.wav
20210111_005000.wav
20210111_005500.wav
```

which would be one hour, then

```
20210111_010000.wav
20210111_010500.wav
20210111_011000.wav
```

and so on.

I need the files split into groups of 12 and then I need a new folder to be created in: "E:/Audiomoth Files/Winter/Rural/Emma/Organised Files"

With the new folders named 'Hour 1', 'Hour 2' and so on.

What is the exact code I need to do this?

As is probably very obvious I'm a complete beginner with R so if the answer could be spelt out in layman's terms that would be brilliant.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Wasn't this question answered?

Comment: I ran the code from the answer you gave on the previous question and nothing seemed to happen

Comment: Nothing in R seems to happen, but look for the folder within your working directory, you should see the files in there separated with regards to hours. Also no one will give you the exact code to your problem, we give approximates then you should twist it to suit the problem you have

Comment: I don't think anything has changed in terms of the working directory folder. It's still just a huge folder with thousands of files. Sorry for asking for exact things it's just if something doesn't work I'm highly unsure and unconfident about changing it myself to make it work. Like I said i'm really just learning this for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

I intentionally used copy instead of cut in order to prevent data from being lost. I edited the answer so the files will keep their old names. I order to give them new names, replace `name` in the last line by `"Part_", i, ".wav"`, for example.

```
# get a list of the paths to all the files
old_files <- list.files("E:/Audiomoth Files/Winter/Rural/Emma/", pattern = "\\.wav$", full.names = TRUE)
# create new directory
dir.create("E:/Audiomoth Files/Winter/Rural/Emma/Organised Files")

# start a loop, repeat as often as there are groups of 12 within the list of files
for(i in 1:(round(length(old_files)/12)+1)){
  # create a directory for the hour
  directory <- paste("E:/Audiomoth Files/Winter/Rural/Emma/Organised Files", "/Hour_", i, sep = "")
  dir.create(directory)
  # select the files that are to copy (I guess it will start with 1*12-11 = 1st file
  # and end with i*12 = 12th file)
  filesToCopy <- old_files[(i*12-11):(i*12)]
  # for those files run another loop:
  for(file in 1:12){
  # get the name of the file
  name <- basename(filesToCopy[file])
  # copy the file to the current directory
   file.copy(filesToCopy[file], paste(directory, "/", name, sep = ""))
  }
}
```

When you're not entirely sure, I'd recommend to copy the files instead of moving them directly (which is what I hope this script here does). You can delete them manually, later on. **After** you checked that everything worked well and all data is where it should be. Otherwise data can be lost due to even small errors, which we do not want to happen.